# Redacting patient name from SQL Server text column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-update

I have a SQL Server 2016 database I use for medical research. I have a table with four columns:

- medical_record number (nchar(20))
- patient_last_name (nchar(100))
- patient_first_name (nchar(100))
- diagnostic_text (text)

I want to remove all protected health information (PHI) from the `diagnostic` column. Unfortunately, sometimes the patient's name is mentioned in this column, and I'd like to redact this information, replacing the patient's name with something like 'XXXXXX'.

The only thing I can think to do is to use a cursor, and loop through each record and use `REPLACE` on each record like:

```
REPLACE (@diagnostic_text, @patient_last_name), 'XXXXX')
```

Is there a better way to do this? I have about 500k rows to process.

I really appreciate any feedback. I'm a doctor and not a database expert. Thanks!

Comment: If `diagnostic_text` is really `text`, you have a mountain of problems ahead of you. Is it possible that the information in diagnostic_text is hand-entered and therefor subject to misspellings, abbreviations, and other "shortcuts" people tend to write?

Comment: `ntext` and `text` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `update`:

```
update mytable
set diagnostic_text = replace(diagnostic_text, patient_last_name, 'XXX')
```

However, this might have side effects, if the name of the patient is contained in some other diagnostic word.

Say the patient is `Bill` and the diagnostic text contains word `'Billable`', it would become `'XXXable'`.

An sligthly safer option is to search for entire words (as delimited by a space):

```
update mytable
set diagnostic_text = ltrim(rtrim(replace(
    ' ' + diagnostic_text + ' ', 
    ' ' + patient_last_name + ' ', 
    ' XXX '
)))
```